# Average TPS calculation for lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, monitoring, weighted-average, dynatrace, tps

In time period of 24 hours , the lambda received 1193 request between 08.29 am and 08.30 am . For the rest of the time the no of request is 1 at 2 pm . How do we calculate the average TPS for this lambda .

In dynatrace , the average tps from throughput metrics changes with time period selected for observation .

Average TPS between 8 am to 12 pm gives 16.1/s . Extending it between 8 am to next day 8 am makes it 1.61/s (3.22/s + 0.002/s) ÷ 2 .

How average tps needs to be calculated at this scenario . Can I rely on the metrics observed from dynatrace